# Calculate all weights at once or individually?

Tags: neural-network

The title says it all. When training a network, do I calculate all the weights at once or calculate them individually?

Comment: Read how backpropagation works. Weights are updated backwards, layer per layer. Once per epoch or per iteration (batch vs online training)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way. However, be aware that updating the weights individually is almost equivalent to updating all of them at once assuming that you are updating the weights given the same input example to the model. Also, updating weights individually requires you to write several for loops and it takes a LONG LONG time to update them. You can do it very fast using vectorization techniques and updating them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

what's your meaning?
When you training a network, you should use all your data, and use the gradient decent algorithm in general to update your weights.
you can use the multi-threading technology to parallel compute some results from your data, then your weights is the average of these results.

Comment: What I mean is, should I calculate each weight one at a time (get output > calculate weight 1 > get output > calculate weight 2 etc.) or should I just do it all at once (get output > calculate all weights > get output etc.)?